# Count different values in one SQL column

Tags: sql

I have a SQL column like this:

```
x_all
--------
bb
aa
aa
bb
cc
bb
cc
cc
cc
dd
```

In this column:

- count of aa is 2,
- count of bb is 3,
- count of cc is 4,
- count of dd is 1

I want to query with SQL and get the result below (sort it x_count desc)

How can I write this SQL query?

```
x_name  x_count
----------------
cc      4
bb      3
aa      2
dd      1
```

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @srtc You have some good answers here. I recommend you mark one of those answers as accepted. You can do that by clicking on the check box by an answer of your choice. That'll give your question closure and others can see that the question has been acceptably answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY` with `ORDER BY DESC` as given below.

```
SELECT x_all AS x_Name, COUNT(x_all) AS x_count
FROM tableName
GROUP BY x_all
ORDER BY COUNT(x_all) DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Select x_all as x_name ,count(x_all)as x_count 
From TABLENAME 
Group by x_all
```

Hope this help you!

Answer (score 1):

Select Count(*) as x_count, x_all as x_name from table group by x_all

Comment: Sorted by x_name. but was found. sort by x_count :         Select Count(*) as x_count, x_all as x_name from table group by x_all order by x_count DESC            thanks.